# Code works in debug but not in release

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mysql-connector

Even though there are plenty of cases like this, and I did search for them, none of them really helped me in any way. The code below works perfectly in debug, but in release mode it crashes, or returns mangled up strings if it doesn't. All optimizations for release mode are turned off, to no result. Using Visual Studio's code analysis found nothing. If it's some kind of memory/buffer thing, then it's currently above my head.

```
case LBN_SELCHANGE:                                                                                
//===========================================================================
//Trying to fill the edit boxes with data fetched from DB
//===========================================================================
{
    string s; 
    wstring str;
    int y;
    int ind = SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_lbList), LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0);
    int index = SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_lbList), LB_GETITEMDATA, (WPARAM)ind, 0);
    string sint = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(index);
    string smt = "SELECT `ID`, `client`, `telnr`, `atnrem`, `papatn`, `gedapr` FROM `tremreg` WHERE `ID` = ";
    string query = smt + sint;
    res = stmt->executeQuery(query.c_str());
    while (res->next())
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= g_iFieldCount + 1; i++)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                y = res->getInt(i);
                SetDlgItemInt(hwnd, IDC_eRemID, y, FALSE);
            }
            else
            {
                s = res->getString(i);
                str = s2ws(s);
                SetDlgItemText(hwnd, 1000 + (i - 1), str.c_str());
            }
        }
    }
    delete res;
}
break;
```

It seems that something goes horribly wrong when fetching strings in release mode. They are filled, with... something. As the first 4 spots in the string are filled with odd characters and null terminators. Here's a screenshot.

http://imgur.com/7TfErwE

And when I convert it to wstring `str`, all that remains is the `char[0]`.

Comment: You should omit from your question the part of your code that work flawlessly. If the problem is with recordset then start with the line `string smt = "SELECT ...`

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance, that the problem doesn't lie in your quoted code but in configuration differences between Debug and Release.

If there's nothing obvious some further details on how exactly your strings get mangled up or what it crashes on might be helpful to assist you :)

Comment: I literally disabled all optimization to make sure it's the same environment as debug. In debug, `test` from DB is `test` when fetched. In release, `test` is something like `"\x1"`. As a side note, which is probably notice. The drop down menu from watching that string's value has yielded me some interesting info. `size = 273`, `capacity = 287`. The DB fields are Varchars. The mangled strings consists mostly of null terminators, and various other things like `\x4` and `\xf`. char[4] to char[7] of the string's contents contain my letters... `116 't'` etc.

Comment: if you disabled optimizations in release, then just debug the release build and find the problem.

Comment: @tenfour I am doing just that. Updated the main post with my new discoveries, which only leave me even more puzzled.